# how to use logout button without authProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

hi react admin community,

I want to use logout button with custom component and router. I have checked documentation but not found any solution.

please suggest to me how I can use it.
below I added my code.

**Adminroot Component**

This is Admin Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import  { UserList } from "../users/users"; 
import Dashboard from './dashboard'; 
import MyLogoutButton from '../auth/logout'; 

const authProvider = {
    logout: params => Promise.resolve(),
};

function Adminroot(props) {
    const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');

    return (
        <div>
            <Admin logoutButton={MyLogoutButton} loginPage={false} dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
                <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
            </Admin>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Adminroot;
```

**MyLogoutButton Component**

This component contains default code which provides react-admin for logout.

Now, when clicks on Logout button. by default redirects to */login* Url.
There renders a Logout component (below written the logout component code) that contains logout logic and redirect to */signin* but it shows blank page until I refresh the page.

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { useLogout } from 'react-admin';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import ExitIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PowerSettingsNew';

const MyLogoutButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const logout = useLogout();
    const handleClick = () => logout();
    return (
        <MenuItem
            onClick={handleClick}
            ref={ref}
        >
            <ExitIcon /> Logout
        </MenuItem>
    );
});

export default MyLogoutButton;
```

**Logout Component**

```
import React , { useContext } from 'react';
import { AppContext } from '../../AppContext';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function Logout(props){
    const {handleSignOut} = useContext(AppContext);
    handleSignOut();
    return props.history.push('/signin');
}
export default Logout;
```

Comment: Any code about what you have achieved?

Comment: I edited my question with code, please have a look.